# Trigger embedded Javascript from url (adwords landing page)

Tags: javascript

I have some Javascript in the header of my site (Opencart) which scrolls the page up to view 3 variants of a product selected from a drop-down menu at the top of the category pages.

```
function getBatt() {
  var myselect = document.getElementById("batt");
  var battery = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById(battery).scrollIntoView();
}
```

I want to trigger this script from the landing page url in my adwords ad in order to display the three variants of the product on the category page, rather than going directly to the product page, which would only dislay one variant of the product. This should create a better user experience.

(Eg the ad is for product bl-4b, the destination url is xxx/NOKIA BATTERIES.
Rather than force the user to manually select the product from the drop-down menu I want to pass the parameter bl-4b (batt) to the function and trigger it on page load.)

Is this possible/advisable without opening a can of worms regarding security?

Answer (score 0):

You could create one url, the url with one parameter for each product, for each ad and then get the parameter with javascript and scroll to that product.